# WCF Service is returning error message which is not understandable

Tags: c#, wcf

From my Library project, I'm making a call to a WCF service, which returns the following error message. The strange thing is that the service does not create any log for this request.

*Server stack trace:

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:

> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   MLibrary.ValidationService.IValidation.DetectEx(Data data)    at
>   MLibrary.ValidationService.ValidationClient.DetectEx(Data data)    at
>   MLibrary.Validator.Change(Int32 duration, List`1 params)*

Comment: Did you try WCF tracing yet ?<configuration>  
   <system.diagnostics>  
      <sources>  
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"   
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"  
                    propagateActivity="true">  
            <listeners>  
               <add name="traceListener"   
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"   
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />  
            </listeners>  
         </source>  
      </sources>  
   </system.diagnostics>  
</configuration>

Comment: Yes, after doing that i got Server stack trace part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web.config added below lines of code. Which will enable server stack trace and we can find the root cause of the issue.

```
<configuration> 
<system.diagnostics> 
    <sources> 
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
            <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners> 
        </source> 
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```